# Django загрузка изображения и вывод

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

Есть Djnago модель, которая выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вывожу данные из модели в HTML шаблон: (Тут возникает ошибка)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вместо изображения выводится какая-то иконка на сайте (url вывел специально чтобы посмотреть )

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вывод терминала:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Настройки и структура:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нашёл и исправил, ошибка была в том, что в   не было .url